# How can I find LGCP random field Lambda values in overall area?

Tags: r, random, attributes

There is a rLGCP model example in the RandomField package.

```
 if(require(RandomFields)) {
  # homogeneous LGCP with exponential covariance function
  X <- rLGCP("exp", 3, var=0.2, scale=.1)

  # inhomogeneous LGCP with Gaussian covariance function
  m <- as.im(function(x, y){5 - 1.5 * (x - 0.5)^2 + 2 * (y - 0.5)^2}, W=owin())
  X <- rLGCP("gauss", m, var=0.15, scale =0.5)
  plot(attr(X, "Lambda"))
  points(X)

  }
```

I think that the Lambda attribute of X does not show the overall values in the overall two dimensional area.

How can I find the overall Lambda values in overall area?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure if this is what you are looking for, but the matrix of values of Lambda for each point in the plot are stored in the `Lambda` attribute of the model created by `spatstat::rLGCP`.

You can access them like this:

```
m <- as.im(function(x, y){5 - 1.5 * (x - 0.5)^2 + 2 * (y - 0.5)^2}, W=owin())
X <- rLGCP("gauss", m, var=0.15, scale = 0.5)
lambda_matrix <- attr(X, "Lambda")$v
```

Now `lambda_matrix` is a 128 x 128 matrix containing the value of Lambda at each point on the grid.